# Blank Authorization header

Tags: c#, authentication, go, header

I have an API written in Golang and a client in C#, they work with `Bearer` token, on the client I add the `Authorization` header but on the server side it is blank.

This is the client C#:

```cs
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUrl);
 //request.PreAuthenticate = true;
 request.ContentType = "application/json";
 request.Method = "PUT";
 request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
 //request.Accept = "application/json";

 using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
 {
     string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sync, new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" });
     stream.Write(serialized);
 }

 try
 {
     using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
     {
         if (((int)response.StatusCode) < 200 || ((int)response.StatusCode) >= 300)
         {
             throw new Exception("error");
         }
     }
 }
 catch (WebException wex)
 {
     var body = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
     throw new HttpRequestException(body);
 }
```

Debugging it, the token is present.

This is the golang server code:

```golang
return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx := r.Context()
        authHeader := r.Header.Get("Authorization")

        _, err := parseAuthHeader(ctx, verifier, authHeader)
        if err != nil {
            render.Render(w, r, httperr.ErrUnauthorized(err.Error()))
            return
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

The variable `authHeader` is blank, but only in production (Google Cloud). If I run it locally, it works. Already tried to add `PreAuthenticate`, did not help. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I used the `http` instead the `https` api link. Adding the `s` solved the problem.